# Why can't spring boot find file in src/main/resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath

I am trying to enable HTTPS for my Spring Boot App based on the instructions in [Spring WS - HTTPS Client-Server Example](https://www.codenotfound.com/2017/04/spring-ws-https-client-server-example.html). The keystore file `server-keystore.jks` is generated using `keytool` and placed in /src/main/resources of my project along with `application.properties`. In the `application.properties`, I have the following:

```
server.port=9443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server-keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.keyAlias=server-keypair
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

When I start the Spring Boot Application inside Eclipse, it fails right away with the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [server-keystore.jks] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

If I remove `classpath` before `server-keystore.jks` in `application.properties`, the launch process will go on a little longer but eventually failed with

```
FileNotFoundException: project-root-dir\server-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

`project-root-dir` is the root path of my project. How do I make Spring Boot aware of the location of this cert file?

Comment: Is the file under `target\classes`?

Comment: Maybe you should build with `mvn`, refresh project in eclipse and then run the Spring boot app.

Comment: @tsolakp it works after I did `mvn clean` and `mvn install`. However no classes in target though

Comment: Probably looking at the wrong target directory then. `mvn install` should create `target` directory on the same level as the `src` directory is.

Comment: @tsolakp there is a target and that's where my jar is. but no classes sub folder